# pySpark DataFrame FloatType() with file coming in as unicode

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Hello I have the following schema:

```
[StructField(record_id,StringType,true), StructField(offer_id,FloatType,true)]
```

The file I am importing is coming in as unicode. 
For sc.textFiles turning unicode to false still pulls a string error. My question is before I load the data into the dataframe do I have to cleanse it (convert unicode to float before saying it is FloatType?

What is the most efficient way to do this especially as a I scale to 1000's of fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is NOT good practice to convert implicitly between unrelated data types. So (almost) no system can help you to do it automagically. Yes, you have to tell the system and system will accept you are taking the risk of failure in future (what happens if the string field contains "abc" suddenly?)
2. You should use a map function as translation layer between your sc.textfile and createDataFrame or apply schema step. All casting to correct data types should happen there.
3. If you have 1000s of fields, you may want to implement an infer-schema mechanism and take some sample of data to decide the schema to use, and then apply it to whole data.

(Assuming Spark 1.3.1 release)